# Split string by array of strings, and include words used to split in final array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to split a string into an array around words in a string array. Right now, I'm using `myString.Split(arrayOfWordsToSplitOn, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, which splits the string, but doesn't include the actual word that it is splitting on.

For example, if I have the string `"My cat and my dog are very lazy"`, and a string array `{"cat", "dog"}`, right now it returns `{"My", "and my", "are very lazy"}`.

However, I would like to have the final output be `{"My", "cat", "and my", "dog", "are very lazy"}`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you could use a regex...

Comment: Do you want to split on word boundaries or also substrings? Your current `String.Split` approach does the latter

Comment: Still a regex would be good to use: `Regex.Split(s, string.Format(@"\b({0})\b", string.Join("|", arrayOfWordsToSplitOn)))`

Comment: Sorry, I understand that word is ambiguous. I'm trying to build a dictionary definition that contains links for words that match other dictionary definitions. I already do a query to determine the list of words that will be linking to other terms. This array will be what I need to split on, so that the linked terms are separate entities in the array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create an alternation based regex out of your list of search words, and wrap that part with a capturing group, `(...)`. Then, add `\s*` to strip the whitespaces around the group and use `Regex.Split`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arrayOfWordsToSplitOn = new List<string> { "cat", "dog" };
        var s = "My cat and my dog are very lazy";
        var pattern = string.Format(@"\s*\b({0})\b\s*", string.Join("|", arrayOfWordsToSplitOn));
        var results = Regex.Split(s, pattern).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
        foreach (var res in results)
            Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/3ALmLT).

Results:

```
My
cat
and my
dog
are very lazy
```

**NOTES:**

- If the search words can contain non-word chars, the pattern should be adjusted as `\b` (word boundaries) might fail the match, and the search "words" will have to be `Regex.Escape`d
- The search word array might need sorting by length and alphabet if you decide to drop word boundaries.

Comment: awesome answer, makes it so easy